# Not able to load my dotnetnuke website on Internet Explorer though it is working fine with other browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, dotnetnuke

I have just integrated my design built using twitter bootstrap, html5, css, jquery with dotnetnuke to create a skin.

The html version in on following URL: [www.siddharthkpandey.co.uk/design/homepage.html](http://www.siddharthkpandey.co.uk/design/homepage.html), [www.siddharthkpandey.co.uk/design/general2.html](http://www.siddharthkpandey.co.uk/design/general2.html)

The Dotnetnuke version is on following URL: [www.siddharthkpandey.co.uk/museum/newdesign.aspx](http://www.siddharthkpandey.co.uk/museum/newdesign.aspx) and [www.siddharthkpandey.co.uk/museum/newdesign/generalpage.aspx](http://www.siddharthkpandey.co.uk/museum/newdesign/generalpage.aspx)

Both the versions works fine with Chrome, Safari and Firefox latest versions. The HTML version also works on IEs but I am not able to figure out what is the problem with the Dotnetnuke version on IEs!

Comment: While using Developer Tools on IE8 I have found that it is using Quirks Mode(Page Default) as Document Mode. When I change this to IE7 standards or IE8 standards the website works quite well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you dont have the correct doctype. Copy one of the .doctype.xml files from the default darknight skin rename this to match the names of your skins example skin.doctype.xml and the refresh your page and it will look correct

Comment: It is working quite well with IE 7,8,9,10 but it crashes in IE6. Need your advice for this problem.